# Excel VBA Moving SharePoint Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, vba

Due to SharePoint's 5000 item limit, I want to run an Excel VBA program to archive folders from a SharePoint "Active" Folder to another SharePoint Folder, called Completed.

The only solution I can find is to use the locally synced folders on a workstation and use FSO.MOVEFOLDER commands.  This works to move the folder and its files.

Is this the best method or is there something better?

Thanks,

AGI_MEG

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using a SharePoint workflow (created with SharePoint Designer or by code, the below assumes designer).

The command you are looking for is

- Copy item from *this list* to *this list*.

You will then want to delete the original item afterwards.

Once this is in place you will want this to run according to your logic. I recommend setting it to run after X time (i.e 6 months after last modified).

This can bee set using retention settings in your library.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at using Information Management Policy Settings to move data.

click library setting > Information management policy settings > Select a content type used within the library that you want to monitor. Enable Retention > Add a retention stage